# Trouble doing simple parse in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm having some basic problem using pyparsing.  Below is the test program and the output of the run.

```
aaron-mac:sql aaron$ more s.py

from pyparsing import *

n = Word(alphanums)
a = Group( n | Group( n + OneOrMore( Suppress(",") + n )))
p = Group( a + Suppress(".") )
print a.parseString("first")
print a.parseString("first,second")
print p.parseString("first.")
print p.parseString("first,second.")


aaron-mac:sql aaron$ python s.py
[['first']]
[['first']]
[[['first']]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "s.py", line 15, in <module>
   print p.parseString("first,second.")
 File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pyparsing.py", line 1032, in parseString
   raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "." (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
aaron-mac:sql aaron$
```

How do I modify the grammar in the test program to parse a list of comma separated names terminated by a period?  I looked in the docs and tried to find a live support list, but decided I was most likely to get a response here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The '|' operator creates a MatchFirst expression, in which the alternatives are evaluated until there is a first match.

Pyparsing works purely left-to-right, applying parser expressions to the input string as it can.  The only lookahead that pyparsing does is whatever you write into the parser.

In this expression:

```
a = Group( n | Group( n + OneOrMore( Suppress(",") + n )))
```

Let's say `n` is just a literal "X".  If this parser was given the input string "X", it would obviously match the leading, lone `n` expression.  If given the string "X,X,X", it would still match just the leading `n`, because that is the first alternative in the parser.

If you turn the expression around to:

```
a = Group( Group( n + OneOrMore( Suppress(",") + n )) | n)
```

then to parse "X" it would first try to match the list, which will fail, and then match the lone `n`.  To parse "X,X,X", the first alternative will be the list expression, which will match.

If you want the longest alternative to match, use the '^' operator, which gives an Or expression.  Or will evaluate all the given alternatives, and then select the longest match.

```
a = Group( n ^ Group( n + OneOrMore( Suppress(",") + n )))
```

You can also simplify this using the pyparsing helper method `delimitedList`.  Parsing lists of the same expression separated by commas is a common case, so rather than see people have to reinvent `expr + ZeroOrMore(Suppress(",") + expr)` over and over, I added `delimitedList` as a standard pyparsing helper.  `delimitedList("X")` would match both "X" and "X,X,X".

Comment: "The only lookahead that pyparsing does is whatever you write into the parser." -- Does this mean that pyparsing may do a lot of backtracking for complex grammars? Like this one for example http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf ?

Comment: If a grammar is doing a lot of backtracking, this can be reduced by enabling packrat parsing (essentially memoizing previously parsed bits).

Comment: You are probably right about "good" grammars.  One could image bad grammars (I think C++ might be one) where the lookahead determines a whole different subtree of the grammar, in which memoization may be less effective.  It's an interesting theoretical question...  Thanks for the great responses!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to cover the case of a comma separated list of names terminated by period you can use the following:

```
from pyparsing import *
p = Word(alphanums)+ZeroOrMore(Suppress(",")+Word(alphanums))+Suppress(".")
```

With this you get the following results:

```
>>> print p.parseString("first.")
['first']
>>> print p.parseString("first,second.")
['first', 'second']
```

The other examples in your question fail because they don't end with a period.